# JavaFX TableView Paginator

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

How use in TableView paginator.?.For This exmple...

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TableView<Student> table;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Student, Integer> id;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Student, String> name;
    @FXML private ObservableList<Student> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    //  @FXML private Pagination pagination;
    // 
    private StudentSQL ssql = new StudentSQL();
    private Stage stage = new Stage();
    private String row;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, Integer>("id"));
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("name"));
        list = ssql.students();
        table.setItems(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You have to use the [Pagination](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Pagination.html) control and implement a page factory. The factory is called for every page that should be displayed and you can use its parameter, the pageIndex, to provide a sublist of items to the TableView:

```
TableView table = ...

private Node createPage(int pageIndex) {

    int fromIndex = pageIndex * rowsPerPage;
    int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + rowsPerPage, data.size());
    table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)));

    return new BorderPane(table);
}


@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Pagination pagination = new Pagination((data.size() / rowsPerPage + 1), 0);
    pagination.setPageFactory(this::createPage);
    ...
}
```

A complete runnable example can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/timbuethe/7becdc4556225e7c5b7b

Comment: Hi! Thanks for providing the method to creating pages with JavaFX. However, I discovered a little problem when testing out your code (this applies to @jewelsea as well). When the size of the data == to the number of rows that one has set in a page, chaos (within the pages) would occur. In this case, an additional (blank) page is created and data refuses to show up on any of the pages. So, I whipped out a quick solution to counteract this problem. Hope it helps! Refer to my post for the code snippet. :)

Comment: It strikes me odd that createPage returns a new BorderPane. That doesn't make sense to me, you simply want to update the table contents.

Answer (score 13):

Note: this solution is inefficient for many tasks.  A better solution would be to use only one table and, on a page change, just change the items in the item list backing the table.

---

Here is some sample code for integrating TableView with a Pagination control.

The code comes from Shakir Quasaroff's answer to an [Oracle JavaFX forum request for a PaginatedTableView control](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2432373/paginatedtableview-control).  The sample code is a pure Java solution, rather than a Java Code/FXML hybrid as in the original question.

```
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
 
public class TablePager extends Application {
 
    final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("1", "Joe", "Pesci"),
            new Person("2", "Audrey", "Hepburn"),
            new Person("3", "Gregory", "Peck"),
            new Person("4", "Cary", "Grant"),
            new Person("5", "De", "Niro"),
            new Person("6", "Katharine", "Hepburn"),
            new Person("7", "Jack", "Nicholson"),
            new Person("8", "Morgan", "Freeman"),
            new Person("9", "Elizabeth", "Taylor"),
            new Person("10", "Marcello", "Mastroianni"),
            new Person("11", "Innokenty", "Smoktunovsky"),
            new Person("12", "Sophia", "Loren"),
            new Person("13", "Alexander", "Kalyagin"),
            new Person("14", "Peter", "OToole"),
            new Person("15", "Gene", "Wilder"),
            new Person("16", "Evgeny", "Evstegneev"),
            new Person("17", "Michael", "Caine"),
            new Person("18", "Jean-Paul", "Belmondo"),
            new Person("19", " Julia", "Roberts"),
            new Person("20", "James", "Stewart"),
            new Person("21", "Sandra", "Bullock"),
            new Person("22", "Paul", "Newman"),
            new Person("23", "Oleg", "Tabakov"),
            new Person("24", "Mary", "Steenburgen"),
            new Person("25", "Jackie", "Chan"),
            new Person("26", "Rodney", "Dangerfield"),
            new Person("27", "Betty", "White"),
            new Person("28", "Eddie", "Murphy"),
            new Person("29", "Amitabh", "Bachchan"),
            new Person("30", "Nicole", "Kidman"),
            new Person("31", "Adriano", "Celentano"),
            new Person("32", "Rhonda", " Fleming's"),
            new Person("32", "Humphrey", "Bogart"));
    private Pagination pagination;
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }
 
    public int itemsPerPage() {
        return 1;
    }
 
    public int rowsPerPage() {
        return 5;
    }
 
    public VBox createPage(int pageIndex) {
        int lastIndex = 0;
        int displace = data.size() % rowsPerPage();
        if (displace > 0) {
            lastIndex = data.size() / rowsPerPage();
        } else {
            lastIndex = data.size() / rowsPerPage() - 1;
 
        }
 
        VBox box = new VBox(5);
        int page = pageIndex * itemsPerPage();
 
        for (int i = page; i < page + itemsPerPage(); i++) {
            TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
            TableColumn numCol = new TableColumn("ID");
            numCol.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("num"));
 
            numCol.setMinWidth(20);
 
            TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
            firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
 
            
            firstNameCol.setMinWidth(160);
 
            TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
            lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));
 
            lastNameCol.setMinWidth(160);
 
            table.getColumns().addAll(numCol, firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
            if (lastIndex == pageIndex) {
                table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(pageIndex * rowsPerPage(), pageIndex * rowsPerPage() + displace)));
            } else {
                table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(pageIndex * rowsPerPage(), pageIndex * rowsPerPage() + rowsPerPage())));
            }
 
 
            box.getChildren().add(table);
        }
        return box;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
 
        pagination = new Pagination((data.size() / rowsPerPage() + 1), 0);
        //   pagination = new Pagination(20 , 0);
        pagination.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red;");
        pagination.setPageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>() {
            @Override
            public Node call(Integer pageIndex) {
                if (pageIndex > data.size() / rowsPerPage() + 1) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    return createPage(pageIndex);
                }
            }
        });
 
        AnchorPane anchor = new AnchorPane();
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(pagination, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(pagination, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(pagination, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(pagination, 10.0);
        anchor.getChildren().addAll(pagination);
        Scene scene = new Scene(anchor, 400, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Table pager");
        stage.show();
    }
 
    public static class Person {
 
        private final SimpleStringProperty num;
        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
 
        private Person(String id, String fName, String lName) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.num = new SimpleStringProperty(id);
        }
 
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }
 
        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }
 
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }
 
        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }
 
        public String getNum() {
            return num.get();
        }
 
        public void setNum(String id) {
            num.set(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample program output:

[image: tablepager]

---

Additionally, the third party, lgpl licensed [TiwulFX library by Panemu](http://tiwulfx.panemu.com/) provides advanced functionality for TableView (including pagination).

Comment: This write become in controller class ?

Comment: No, the solution in this answer is not fxml based, it is not related to a Controller class.

Comment: I think the provided example contains a lot of unnecessary code and does unnecessary work. Why is the tableView recreated for every page? And why is a created in a for loop? See my answer for a cleaned up version. No offense.

Comment: Nice optimization Tim.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered a little problem when testing out the pagination code produced on this thread. When the size of the data == to the number of rows that one has set in a page, chaos (within the pages) would occur. In this case, an additional (blank) page is created and data refuses to show up on any of the pages. I believe that the following snippet should solve that issue (if anyone else is encountering the same problem as me). This snippet should come before declaring the Pagination variable.

```
int numOfPages = 1;
if (data.size() % rowsPerPage == 0) {
  numOfPages = data.size() / rowsPerPage;
} else if (data.size() > rowsPerPage) {
  numOfPages = data.size() / rowsPerPage + 1;
}
Pagination pagination = new Pagination((numOfPages), 0);
pagination.setPageFactory(this::createPage);
```

Hope it helps!