# Pagination Control with tableview / max rows per page

Tags: javafx

I want to use Pagination control with a tableview. A dependency is, that the amount of rows in a page is less or equal the amount of max visible rows in the table viewport.

The vertical scrollbar should be invisible and navigation is handled by pagination control buttons.

Are there any best practices about how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX TableView Paginator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349185/javafx-tableview-paginator)

Comment: no it is not a duplicate. They use a fixed number for the rows per page. I want to calculate the size of a cell in dependency of font style, textsize...