# How to display data from .txt file using JavaFX GUI Application

Tags: java, javafx, bufferedreader, filereader

I would like to display a data from .txt report file using JavaFX. In my code, I'm trying to use Labels and Vbox to display the info in multiple formats in a GUI to scene. However, I'm having terrible outputting my results as GUI instead of the console. I tried to research my issue but I couldn't find the piece of info that I need to solve the problem.

This is the report I need to display as a GUI Application using JavaFX:

[image: Image from console NOT from the GUI]

This is what my code displays as a GUI:

[image: Image when I run my GUI]

Here is my source code:

```java
package sample;

public class CustomerSale {

    // Details of reports
    private String zipCodeExtension;

    private int customerNumber;

    private String customerName;

    private int purchaseDate;

    private String make;

    private int purchasePrice;

    private int yearOfVehicle;

    private int satisfactionRating;


    // Create constructor argument

    public CustomerSale(String zipCodeExtension, int customerNumber, String customerName,
                        int purchaseDate, String make, int purchasePrice,
                        int yearOfVehicle, int satisfactionRating) {
        this.zipCodeExtension = zipCodeExtension;
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.purchaseDate = purchaseDate;
        this.make = make;
        this.purchasePrice = purchasePrice;
        this.yearOfVehicle = yearOfVehicle;
        this.satisfactionRating = satisfactionRating;
    }

    // Create getters and setters

    public String getMake() {

        return make;

    }

    public String getZipCodeExtension() {

        return zipCodeExtension;

    }


    public int getCustomerNumber() {

        return customerNumber;

    }

    public String getCustomerName() {

        return customerName;

    }

    public int getPurchaseDate() {

        return purchaseDate;

    }

    public double getPurchasePrice() {

        return purchasePrice;

    }

    public int getYearOfVehicle() {

        return yearOfVehicle;

    }

    public int getSatisfactionRating() {

        return satisfactionRating;

    }
}
```

```java
package sample;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;


/**
 ABC used cars report Application
 */

public class FinalGUIOutput extends Application {

    final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 750, // Window width in pixels
              WINDOW_HEIGHT = 150; // Window height in pixels

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Launch the application
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {

        // Create a Label to display the heading and page number.
        Label headingLabel = new Label("---------------------------------------------------------ABC USED CARS--------------------------------------------------------");

        Label pageNumber = new Label(
                "-------------------------------------------------------PAGE 1-----------------------------------------------------------------");
//        Label pageFormat = new Label("%-19s%-15s%-21s%-15s%-20s%-17s%-12s%-20s\n", "|ZIP CODE-EXT|", "|CUST No.|", "|CUSTOMER NAME|", "|DoP|",
//                "|MAKE|", "|PRICE|", "|YEAR|", "|RATE|");
        Label pageLine = new Label(
                "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        // Create an empty Label to display the result.
        Label resultLabel = new Label();

        File carsInfo = new File("custsale.txt");
        Scanner carsScanner = new Scanner(carsInfo);
        String format = "%-20s%-14s%-21s%-16s%-19s$%-17s%-14s%-20s\n";


        final int pageSize = 30;
        int carCounter = 0;

        while (carsScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            if (carCounter % pageSize == 0) {
                printPageHeader(carCounter / pageSize + 1);
            }

            // Read the carsScanner
            String zipCodeExtension = carsScanner.nextLine();
            int customerNumber = Integer.parseInt(carsScanner.nextLine());
            String customerName = carsScanner.nextLine();
            int purchaseDate = Integer.parseInt(carsScanner.nextLine());
            String make = carsScanner.nextLine();
            int purchasePrice = Integer.parseInt(carsScanner.nextLine());
            int yearOfVehicle = Integer.parseInt(carsScanner.nextLine());
            int satisfactionRating = Integer.parseInt(carsScanner.nextLine());

            CustomerSale custsale = new CustomerSale(zipCodeExtension, customerNumber, customerName,
                    purchaseDate, make, purchasePrice, yearOfVehicle, satisfactionRating);

            // Display the report
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,#####");
            System.out.printf(format, custsale.getZipCodeExtension(), custsale.getCustomerNumber(),
                    custsale.getCustomerName(), custsale.getPurchaseDate(), custsale.getMake(),
                    df.format(custsale.getPurchasePrice()), custsale.getYearOfVehicle(),
                    custsale.getSatisfactionRating());

            // Increment the car counter
            carCounter++;
        }

        carsScanner.close();

        /**
            GUI Display
         */

        // Put the HBox, calcButton and resultLabel in a VBox.
        VBox vbox = new VBox(10,headingLabel, pageNumber, pageLine, resultLabel);

        // Set the VBox's alignment to center.
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Set the VBox's padding to 10 pixels
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // Create a Scene with the VBox as its root node.
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        // set the scene's alignment to center.
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        //Add the Scene to the Stage
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setTitle("ABC Used Cars");

        // Show the window
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private static void printPageHeader(int i) {
        // Create a Label to display the heading and page number.
        Label headingLabel = new Label("---------------------------------------------------------ABC USED CARS--------------------------------------------------------");

        Label pageNumber = new Label(
                "-------------------------------------------------------" + "PAGE " + i + "-----------------------------------------------------------------");
//        Label pageFormat = new Label("%-19s%-15s%-21s%-15s%-20s%-17s%-12s%-20s\n", "|ZIP CODE-EXT|", "|CUST No.|", "|CUSTOMER NAME|", "|DoP|",
//                "|MAKE|", "|PRICE|", "|YEAR|", "|RATE|");
        Label pageLine = new Label(
                "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

}
```

And finally here's my .txt file report that I'm trying to pull data from:

```
46410-1234
1001
ALBERT, CARL T.
08252001
FORD
0255000
1991
2
46307-1201
1003
ANDREWS, ROBERT
08262001
CHEVROLET
0700000
1958
0
46423-2311
1008
ANZIO, RAFELINO
09012001
CHEVROLET
0456050
1978
0
46424-0121
1010
ASHLEY, WILLIAM B.
09022001
PIERCE-ARROW
1240000
1932
2
46375-3110
1015
ATKINSON, MARK
08272001
STUDEBAKER
0050000
1958
1
46405-1291
1025
AVERY, ALFRED A.
08292001
HUDSON
0230000
1954
1
46301-1234
1031
BEZZMEK, JENNIFER
08272001
FORD
0455000
1995
2
46303-1201
1033
BLAKE, DONALD
08292001
FORD
0722050
1989
1
46413-2311
1041
BLONDELL, BONNIE
09042001
CHEVROLET
0356050
1988
1
46404-0121
1045
BONADIO, JAMES
09032001
PIERCE-ARROW
1150000
1935
2
46307-3110
1055
BUCKO, ONIEDA
08282001
STUDEBAKER
0245000
1964
1
46410-1291
1056
BYMANN, FREDRICK
08292001
FORD
0330000
1994
1
46342-1234
1061
CALBERT, RONALD
09052001
FORD
0355000
1993
2
46307-1211
1063
CHELSEA, MARTHA S.
08302001
DODGE BROS.
0350000
1935
0
46410-2311
1067
CLAFLIN, WAYNE R.
09012001
CHEVROLET
0456050
1990
2
46410-0121
1070
COLE, CHARLES C.
09022001
PIERCE-ARROW
1050000
1929
2
46305-3111
1075
COLEMAN, THOMAS
08272001
STUDEBAKER
0167050
1961
1
46410-1221
1076
COLWELL, RICHARD L.
08292001
HUDSON
0430000
1940
1
46414-1231
1080
COOPER, JOHNATHAN
09052001
FORD
1256000
1996
2
46307-1201
2002
COREY, SARAH D.
08272001
CHEVROLET
0650050
1994
0
46421-2311
2004
CRACKLIN, GOODMAN
09012001
CHEVROLET
1456050
1996
0
46323-0121
2011
CRAWFORD, TIMOTHY
09012001
PIERCE-ARROW
1040000
1931
2
46315-3110
2012
CURRIE, RAYMOND
08282001
STUDEBAKER
0150025
1956
1
46425-1291
2024
CYBORG, IZORE M.
09052001
HUDSON
0130000
1949
1
46410-1234
2031
DALTON, DAVID P.
08252001
FORD
0234000
1990
2
46307-1201
2043
DAVIES, RALPH O.
08262001
CHEVROLET
0333000
1989
0
46423-2311
2048
DENNICK, DONNA
09012001
CHEVROLET
0656025
1995
0
46424-0121
2050
DERBIN, DEANNA
09022001
PIERCE-ARROW
1640025
1937
2
46375-3110
2065
DONNEHUE, PHILLIP
09042001
STUDEBAKER
0054000
1966
1
46405-1291
2085
DOPPLER, RADAR O.
08302001
HUDSON
0311000
1951
1
46310-1234
2091
DUNLOP, RITA
08252001
FORD
1450045
1996
2
46303-1201
3003
DYKES, CYNTHIA
08262001
FORD
0410050
1987
1
46413-2311
3011
EATON, ESTER B.
09012001
CHEVROLET
1356050
1996
0
46404-0121
3015
EFFLEY, BAILY
09022001
PIERCE-ARROW
1446045
1933
2
46307-3110
3025
EGGERTON, AMANDA
08292001
STUDEBAKER
0335000
1965
1
46410-1291
3026
EPPLEY, DAVID
08282001
FORD
0414000
1995
1
46342-1234
3031
ERKLE, ROSA
09032001
FORD
0355020
1993
2
46307-1211
3043
FARNSWORTH, WESLEY
09052001
DODGE BROS.
1150000
1996
0
46410-2311
3047
FLANNERY, JAMES
09012001
CHEVROLET
0450050
1992
0
46410-0121
3050
FOREMAN, OTTO J.
09022001
PIERCE-ARROW
0940000
1927
2
46305-3111
3055
FOWLER, KATHLEEN
08272001
STUDEBAKER
0267050
1964
1
46410-1221
3056
FURNACE, DAVID
08292001
HUDSON
0530000
1948
1
46414-1231
3061
GALLAGHER, CLARENCE
09042001
FORD
1006000
1992
2
46307-1201
3062
GENNERRO, TONY S.
08302001
CHEVROLET
0320050
1989
0
46421-2311
3066
GOEBEL, NANCY K.
09022001
CHEVROLET
0643050
1990
0
46323-0121
3072
GUNTHER, FREDERICK
09032001
PIERCE-ARROW
1260000
1930
2
46315-3110
3080
HAINES, MARSHALL
08292001
STUDEBAKER
02500251
959
1
46425-1291
3094
HANCOCK, JONATHON
09032001
HUDSON
0330000
1953
1
46423-2311
3098
HARTNETT, ROBERTO
09052001
CHEVROLET
0326040
1988
0
46424-0121
4005
HENNING, SONIA
09052001
PIERCE-ARROW
1305000
1928
2
46375-3110
4009
HORNSBY, ROGERS
08252001
STUDEBAKER
0167500
1962
1
46405-1291
4012
HYATT, JANET F.
08302001
HUDSON
0155000
1951
1
46301-1234
4021
IDZIOR, RAYMOND
09012001
FORD
1460000
1996
2
46303-1201
4022
JENNINGS, WILLIAM
08262001
FORD
0612040
1992
1
46410-2311
4024
JOHNSON, JACK
09032001
CHEVROLET
0256050
1985
0
46404-0121
4032
KULKA, ROBERT C.
09042001
PIERCE-ARROW
0970000
1934
2
46307-3110
4035
KURTZ, DONALD
08302001
STUDEBAKER
0345000
1966
1
46410-1291
4038
LEVANDOWSKI, JILL
08282001
DODGE BROS.
0430000
1988
1
46342-1234
4044
METZ, ARNOLD E.
09012001
FORD
1323000
1996
2
46307-1211
4046
NORRIS, CHARLES S.
09052001
CHEVROLET
0844000
1992
0
46410-2311
4047
NOWAKOWSKI, ALFRED
09012001
DODGE BROS.
0656050
1994
1
46410-0121
4053
O'BOYLE, NIEL
09032001
PIERCE-ARROW
1550000
1938
2
46305-3111
4056
O'BRIAN, PATRICK
08302001
STUDEBAKER
0347050
1962
1
46410-1221
4059
PATTERSON, LENNI R.
08292001
HUDSON
0250000
1946
1
46414-1231
4061
PERRY, SHAMUS
09052001
FORD
0895000
1994
2
46307-1201
4066
REED, ROBERT B.
08272001
CHEVROLET
0740050
1996
0
46421-2311
4067
RODRIGUEZ, ALONZO
09052001
DODGE BROS.
1050050
1995
0
46323-0121
4073
SANCHEZ, HENRY
09012001
PIERCE-ARROW
0830000
1925
2
46315-3110
4081
SWARTZ, HECTOR
08282001
STUDEBAKER
0075025
1954
1
46301-1234
4084
TORREZ, MARTIN
08272001
FORD
0565000
1994
2
46303-1201
4090
TUTTLE, MARK
08292001
FORD
0710050
1996
1
46413-2311
4094
WARNER, JACK
09042001
CHEVROLET
0856050
1996
0
46404-0121
4115
YACKLEY, YOURTO
09042001
PIERCE-ARROW
1000000
1930
2
```

Thank you.

Comment: don't delete and repost the exact same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67478960/how-to-display-data-from-txt-file-using-javafx-gui-application - instead edit the previous to make it answerable

Comment: I edited and developed my question so the others can answer it. What are you recommending to make it answerable?

Comment: Please take the [tour]. read [ask] and then [edit] this question accordingly. As it is currently written, it seems like you're just asking us to write the entire GUI application for you. You should work through a basic JavaFX tutorial first either way.

Comment: @Zephyr, my friend thank you so much for the instructions. I tried my best to organize my question and ask appropriately. I also did lot's of research before I post here. I was extremely stuck on this problem and there no where I want the whole GUI application, I did most of the work byself. I'm just learning from you and the others. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you could use a combination of `TableView` and `Pagination` like it is described in this posting: [JavaFX TableView Paginator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15349741/13561971)

Here is an example:

**App.java:**

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class App extends Application {

    ObservableList<CustomerSale> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(readFromFile());

    public int itemsPerPage() {
        return 1;
    }

    public int rowsPerPage() {
        return 30;
    }

    public VBox createPage(int pageIndex) {
        int lastIndex;
        int displace = data.size() % rowsPerPage();
        if (displace > 0) {
            lastIndex = data.size() / rowsPerPage();
        } else {
            lastIndex = data.size() / rowsPerPage() - 1;

        }

        VBox box = new VBox(5);
        int page = pageIndex * itemsPerPage();

        for (int i = page; i < page + itemsPerPage(); i++) {

            // Create table and its columns:
            TableView<CustomerSale> table = new TableView<>();

            TableColumn<CustomerSale, String> headerCol = new TableColumn<>("ABC USED CARS");

            TableColumn<CustomerSale, String> zipCodeExtensionCol = new TableColumn<>("ZIP CODE-EXT");
            TableColumn<CustomerSale, String> customerNameCol = new TableColumn<>("CUSTOMER NAME");
            TableColumn<CustomerSale, String> makeCol = new TableColumn<>("MAKE");
            TableColumn<CustomerSale, Integer> customerNumberCol = new TableColumn<>("CUST No.");
            TableColumn<CustomerSale, Integer> purchaseDateCol = new TableColumn<>("DoP");
            TableColumn<CustomerSale, Integer> purchasePriceCol = new TableColumn<>("PRICE");
            TableColumn<CustomerSale, Integer> yearOfVehicleCol = new TableColumn<>("YEAR");
            TableColumn<CustomerSale, Integer> satisfactionRatingCol = new TableColumn<>("RATE");

            headerCol.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(zipCodeExtensionCol, customerNumberCol, customerNameCol, purchaseDateCol,
                    makeCol, purchasePriceCol, yearOfVehicleCol, satisfactionRatingCol));

            table.getColumns().add(headerCol);

            // Set value factories:
            zipCodeExtensionCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().zipCodeExtensionProperty());
            customerNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().customerNameProperty());
            makeCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().makeProperty());
            customerNumberCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().customerNumberProperty().asObject());
            purchaseDateCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().purchaseDateProperty().asObject());
            purchasePriceCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().purchasePriceProperty().asObject());
            yearOfVehicleCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().yearOfVehicleProperty().asObject());
            satisfactionRatingCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().satisfactionRatingProperty().asObject());

            // Custom cell for currency:
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
            DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) nf;
            df.applyPattern("¤###,###");
            purchasePriceCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if ((item == null || empty))
                        setText(null);
                    else
                        setText(df.format(item.intValue()));
                }
            });

            if (lastIndex == pageIndex)
                table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(pageIndex
                        * rowsPerPage(), pageIndex * rowsPerPage() + displace)));
             else
                table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(pageIndex
                        * rowsPerPage(), pageIndex * rowsPerPage() + rowsPerPage())));

            box.getChildren().add(table);
        }
        return box;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Pagination pagination = new Pagination((data.size() / rowsPerPage() + 1), 0);

        pagination.setPageFactory(pageIndex -> {
            if (pageIndex > data.size() / rowsPerPage() + 1)
                return null;
            else
                return createPage(pageIndex);
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pagination));
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Get the data from the text file.
     *
     * @return list with data
     */
    private List<CustomerSale> readFromFile() {
        List<CustomerSale> result = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Objects.requireNonNull(App.class.getResource(
                "/org/example/data.txt")).getFile()))) {

            String line;
            int counter = 0;
            CustomerSale customerSale = new CustomerSale();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                switch (counter) {
                    case 0 -> customerSale.setZipCodeExtension(line);
                    case 1 -> customerSale.setCustomerNumber(Integer.parseInt(line));
                    case 2 -> customerSale.setCustomerName(line);
                    case 3 -> customerSale.setPurchaseDate(Integer.parseInt(line));
                    case 4 -> customerSale.setMake(line);
                    case 5 -> customerSale.setPurchasePrice(Integer.parseInt(line));
                    case 6 -> customerSale.setYearOfVehicle(Integer.parseInt(line));
                    case 7 -> customerSale.setSatisfactionRating(Integer.parseInt(line));
                }

                ++counter;

                if (counter == 8) {
                    result.add(customerSale);
                    customerSale = new CustomerSale();
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**CustomerSale.java:**

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class CustomerSale {

    private final StringProperty
            zipCodeExtension,
            customerName,
            make;

    private final IntegerProperty
            customerNumber,
            purchaseDate,
            purchasePrice,
            yearOfVehicle,
            satisfactionRating;


    public CustomerSale() {
        zipCodeExtension = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        customerName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        make = new SimpleStringProperty("");

        customerNumber = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);
        purchaseDate = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);
        purchasePrice = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);
        yearOfVehicle = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);
        satisfactionRating = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);
    }

    public CustomerSale(String zipCodeExtension,
                        int customerNumber,
                        String customerName,
                        int purchaseDate,
                        String make,
                        int purchasePrice,
                        int yearOfVehicle,
                        int satisfactionRating) {
        this();
        setZipCodeExtension(zipCodeExtension);
        setCustomerNumber(customerNumber);
        setCustomerName(customerName);
        setPurchaseDate(purchaseDate);
        setMake(make);
        setPurchasePrice(purchasePrice);
        setYearOfVehicle(yearOfVehicle);
        setSatisfactionRating(satisfactionRating);
    }

    public String getZipCodeExtension() {
        return zipCodeExtension.get();
    }

    public StringProperty zipCodeExtensionProperty() {
        return zipCodeExtension;
    }

    public void setZipCodeExtension(String zipCodeExtension) {
        this.zipCodeExtension.set(zipCodeExtension);
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName.get();
    }

    public StringProperty customerNameProperty() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName.set(customerName);
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make.get();
    }

    public StringProperty makeProperty() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make.set(make);
    }

    public int getCustomerNumber() {
        return customerNumber.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty customerNumberProperty() {
        return customerNumber;
    }

    public void setCustomerNumber(int customerNumber) {
        this.customerNumber.set(customerNumber);
    }

    public int getPurchaseDate() {
        return purchaseDate.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty purchaseDateProperty() {
        return purchaseDate;
    }

    public void setPurchaseDate(int purchaseDate) {
        this.purchaseDate.set(purchaseDate);
    }

    public int getPurchasePrice() {
        return purchasePrice.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty purchasePriceProperty() {
        return purchasePrice;
    }

    public void setPurchasePrice(int purchasePrice) {
        this.purchasePrice.set(purchasePrice);
    }

    public int getYearOfVehicle() {
        return yearOfVehicle.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty yearOfVehicleProperty() {
        return yearOfVehicle;
    }

    public void setYearOfVehicle(int yearOfVehicle) {
        this.yearOfVehicle.set(yearOfVehicle);
    }

    public int getSatisfactionRating() {
        return satisfactionRating.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty satisfactionRatingProperty() {
        return satisfactionRating;
    }

    public void setSatisfactionRating(int satisfactionRating) {
        this.satisfactionRating.set(satisfactionRating);
    }
}
```

**Preview:**

[image: preview]

Comment: You code well worked well for me. There is only one more issue, how can I list 30 cars per page, on the report. Each page is to have headings and a page number. Just like my first pic in my question? Thank you and I appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Just combine `TableView` with `Paginator` like here: [JavaFX TableView Paginator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349185/javafx-tableview-paginator/15349741#15349741)

Comment: Could you please edit/update your code so I can see is that can be done. We should have another headercol under ABC Used cars which then updates our list after 30 pages. I think we gonna use loop for updating the header after each 30 pages. Could you please show me how can be done by updating your code? Thanks!

Comment: I updated the example. I'm not sure if it is possible to put the navigation area of the pagination control into a second header column.

Comment: @anko neat solution, but I would suggest next time that you do not give a completely coded example, maybe a big hint for the OP to do things himself. :)

Comment: so you did the OP's homework for him/her .. completely - how lucky s/he is and how unlucky current classmates and future fellow workers ;)

Comment: Thank you so so much @anko, I appreciate your help as I'm learning from you and the others. You're a living legend.

Comment: @Renis1235 I understand your concern, I did my research before I decide to post on here. Nothing is wrong when someone gets stuck to have some help.

Comment: @kleopatra, my friend this is not homework, this is a challenge project I've been trying to solve and I did most of the work by myself. Thank you anyways.